# How Do I Make FLATTEN Work for Non-Contiguous Ranges?

Tags: arrays, excel, lambda, excel-formula, flatten

I have a `FLATTEN` LAMBDA function that flattens data in an array. This works well, but I want to integrate another array argument so I can use non-contiguous ranges.

In my example, the range `A1:B6` is housed in `array` and returns the flattened data.

How can I include an `array2` argument that accepts `D1:D6` as an additional range?

[image: Example]

Formula:

```
FLATTEN =

LAMBDA(array,

LET(
    rows,ROWS(array),
    columns,COLUMNS(array),
    sequence,SEQUENCE(rows*columns),
    quotient,QUOTIENT(sequence-1,columns)+1,
    mod,MOD(sequence-1,columns)+1,

    INDEX(IF(array="","",array),quotient,mod)

    )   
)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit 7/4/22**:

ms365 now has introduced a function called [`VSTACK()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vstack-function-a4b86897-be0f-48fc-adca-fcc10d795a9c) and [`TOCOL()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/tocol-function-22839d9b-0b55-4fc1-b4e6-2761f8f122ed) which allows for the the functionality that we were missing from GS's `FLATTEN()` (and works even smoother)

In your case the formula could become:

```
=TOCOL(A1:D6,1)
```

And that small formula (where the 2nd parameter tells the function to ignore empty cells) would replace everything else from below here. If `C1:C6` would hold values you don't want to incorporate you can try things like:

```
=VSTACK(TOCOL(A1:B6),D1:D6)
```

---

**Previous Answer**:

You can't really create a `LAMBDA()` with an unknown number (beforehand) of arrays to include in flatten. The fact that you have arrays of multiple columns will contribute to the "trickyness". One way to 'flatten' multiple columns in this specific way would be:

[image]

Formula in `G1`:

```
=LET(X,CHOOSE({1,2,3},A1:A6,B1:B6,D1:D6),Y,COLUMNS(X),Z,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(X)),INDEX(X,CEILING(Z/Y,1),MOD(Z-1,Y)+1))
```

---

EDIT: As per your comment, you can extend this as such:

```
=LET(X,CHOOSE({1,2,3},IF(A1:A6="","",A1:A6),IF(B1:B6="","",B1:B6),IF(D1:D6="","",D1:D6)),Y,COLUMNS(X),Z,SEQUENCE(ROWS(X)*Y),FLAT,INDEX(X,CEILING(Z/Y,1),MOD(Z-1,Y)+1),FILTER(FLAT,FLAT<>""))
```

Comment: That works, except when I delete a value from one of the arrays, the blank appears as a zero.

Comment: Replacing `INDEX(X,CEILING(Z/Y,1),MOD(Z-1,Y)+1)` with `list, INDEX(X,CEILING(Z/Y,1),MOD(Z-1,Y)+1), IF(LEN(list) = 0,"", list)` should work

Comment: @Tragamor, sorry I had to rewrite my comment. The trickyness here is that `CHOOSE()` will change empty in a zero. Therefor we need to handle the empty cells at the source. See the edit.

Comment: What about if you use choose as column indices to slice A1:D6 instead? the code may be more concise as I can see this bloating if you have many more columns

Comment: @Tragamor, you are spot on. There is no 'FLATTEN()' and trying to recreate this is tricky. Your suggestion though is *only*  going to work if OP actually has his data in those cells. I read the question as though the 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc array does not necessarily have to reside on the same tab in the same rows.

Comment: The other thing I've noticed is the behaviour when the arrays have varying row counts. Google Sheets' FLATTEN function is a bit more flexible in that respect.

Comment: It may be better to have a second function which is a 'list append' function? You could generate 1D lists of contiguous ranges from the Lambda function then append 1D lists together (havent' seen code for that though)

Comment: @Tragamor, another good suggestion, however that would not work nomore if you need to list items from left to right first accounting for each array (see the results above). GS has this issue down way better.

Answer (score 2):

It's a cheat, but:

```
FLATTEN =

LAMBDA(array,

LET(
    rows,ROWS(array),
    columns,COLUMNS(array),
    sequence,SEQUENCE(rows*columns),
    quotient,QUOTIENT(sequence-1,columns)+1,
    mod,MOD(sequence-1,columns)+1,
    unpiv, INDEX(array,quotient,mod),
    FILTER(unpiv, unpiv<>"")

    )   
)
```

Where your array has been extended to A1:D6 as the input.

> I think JvdV's answer will be the best depending on the input format
> you want, but I had already written this out, so here goes...

You could do:

```
=LET( array1, A1:B6, array2, D1:D6,

      rows1,ROWS(array1),     rows2,ROWS(array2),
      columns1,COLUMNS(array1),   columns2,COLUMNS(array2),
      rows, MIN(rows1, rows2),
      columns, columns1 + columns2,
      sequence,SEQUENCE(rows*columns),
      quotient,QUOTIENT(sequence-1,columns)+1,
      mod,MOD(sequence-1,columns)+1,

      IFERROR(INDEX( IF( ISBLANK(array1),"",array1),quotient,mod),
              INDEX(IF( ISBLANK(array2),"",array2),quotient,MOD(sequence-1,columns2)+1) )

)
```

It will take multi-column/row inputs to both arrays.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but that is a bit of a stopgap solution really. I need to find a way of having an additional `array` argument.

Comment: @Statto - when there is a blank in either of the arrays, do you want it to appear as "" or get skipped?

Comment: I want it to appear as "".

Comment: @Statto - ok, this does that. I really like the solution of JvdV as it is so parsimonious in it's processing, but the inputs have to be made column-by-column. For a LAMBDA function, it might be better to build a column-wise append and call your FLATTEN with the APPENDC as the input. e.g., `FLATTEN(APPENDC(A1:A6,D1:D6))`

Comment: @Statto - Last comment was unclear: ok, this does that. I really like the solution of JvdV as it is so parsimonious in its processing, but the inputs have to be made column-by-column. For a LAMBDA function, that's tedious. Perhaps it would be better to keep your current FLATTEN as is and build a column-wise append LAMBDA function (let's call it APPENDC) and call your FLATTEN with the APPENDC as the input. e.g., `FLATTEN(APPENDC(A1:A6,D1:D6))`

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the article [here](https://exceluser.com/6534/how-to-stack-and-shelve-dynamic-arrays/) and updating based upon observations about empty values in the arrays and allowing varying sized arrays we can get two formulae which you should be able to translate to `Named LAMBDA` functions for 'stacking' and 'shelving' arrays.

> Stack Arrays

```
=LET(rngA, A1:C5, rngB, A9:D11,
rowsA, ROWS(rngA), rowsB, ROWS(rngB),
NumCols, MAX(COLUMNS(rngA), COLUMNS(rngB)),
SeqRow, SEQUENCE(rowsA + rowsB), SeqCol, SEQUENCE(1, NumCols),
Result, IF(SeqRow <= rowsA, INDEX(IF(rngA="","",rngA), SeqRow, SeqCol), 
    INDEX(IF(rngB="","",rngB), SeqRow-rowsA, SeqCol)),
arr, IFERROR(Result,""), arr)
```

> Shelve Arrays

```
=LET(rngA, A1:C5, rngB, B8:D12,
colsA, COLUMNS(rngA), colsB, COLUMNS(rngB),
NumRows, MAX(ROWS(rngA), ROWS(rngB)),
SeqRow, SEQUENCE(NumRows), SeqCol, SEQUENCE(1, colsA + colsB),
Result, IF(SeqCol <= colsA, INDEX(IF(rngA="","",rngA), SeqRow, SeqCol),
    INDEX(IF(rngB="","",rngB), SeqRow, SeqCol-colsA ) ),
arr, IFERROR(Result,""), arr)
```

Once you have a contiguous array, you can apply the formula you already have:

> Updated to use a spill range for ease of testing...

```
=LET(data, A1#,
rows, ROWS(data), cols, COLUMNS(data),
seq, SEQUENCE(rows*cols,,0),
list, INDEX(IF(data="", "", data), QUOTIENT(seq, cols)+1, MOD(seq, cols)+1),
FILTER(list, LEN(list)>0))
```

This approach is really geared towards the `named LAMBDA` functions because otherwise you will end up with monstrous formulae and the other approaches may well be better in that case.