# Polyfill for Excel HSTACK and VSTACK array functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

Microsoft has announced many new array functions (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-new-text-and-array-functions/ba-p/3186066), including `HSTACK` and `VSTACK`, which combine several arrays into one by (unsurprisingly!) "stacking" them horizontally or vertically.  The new functions are currently only available for some users in the Beta channel.

I am building a spreadsheet where those functions would be incredibly useful, but it has to be used by other users in the Current channel. I have three "tables" (not Excel tables, but table=shaped grids of data), with the same columns, where each column is an array formula. I would like to consolidate them into a single table, and refer to the entire content as to a single array.

Is it possible to implement some version of `HSTACK` and `VSTACK` with other array formulas?

Notes:

- I already have access to the other, slightly older, array formulas such as `SEQUENCE`, `FILTER`, `MAP`, `SCAN`, `REDUCE`, as well as `LAMBDA`.
- I assume that any replacement formula would be very inefficient compared to a native implementation, but this is not an issue in my case.
- In my case, I already know that the arrays will have compatible sizes (e.g. `HSTACK` a 3 rows x 2 columns and 3 rows x 4 columns arrays), but I don't know the size in advance.
- A pure formula would be preferable to a VBA UDF, but the latter could be a good solution too.

Comment: So show an example so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Sample data will help people helping you =)

Comment: here is a udf Vstack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655098/replicate-google-sheets-array1-array2-function-in-microsoft-excel-as-user-def  It uses ranges but should be able to be changed to arrays fairly simply.

Comment: I have explained the problem better

Comment: `Stacking` and `Shelving` non-contiguous arrays: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71116003/3688861

Answer (score 5):

Here is a formula that does the vertical stacking, the ranges can be replaced with arrays, but it only does two and is not as robust as the new formula will be:

```
=LET(
 rngone,A1:D6,
 rngtwo,E1:I6,
rwone,ROWS(rngone),
mxseq,SEQUENCE(,MAX(COLUMNS(rngone),COLUMNS(rngtwo))),
seq,SEQUENCE(rwone+ROWS(rngtwo)),
IFERROR(CHOOSE((seq>rwone)+1,INDEX(rngone,seq,mxseq),INDEX(rngtwo,seq-rwone,mxseq)),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Only distantly related, but I'm guessing [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62204826/excel-unique-across-columns) will need updated based on the rollout of new formulas... NVM, Jvdv already has.

Comment: I plan on updating both with the new formula when I get home.  I have them on my own excel, but not at work.

Comment: Actually, on your link, jvdv already took care of adding to theirs.  So I will skip that one.

Comment: Yeah, I'm asking that Jvdv's answer be the accepted one. Mine does not deserve to be, as it's rather inferior.