# Emula VSTACK formula in VBA because it's not yet available on all computers

Tags: excel, vba, custom-functions-excel

I was stoked to find about VSTACK and HSTACK formulas, because I could trim down some huge formulas, by merging multiple named ranges with VSTACK, and then using index to find a sum in  a specified column, using a formula like:
`=SUM(INDEX(vStack(VBA_REG_NIS1,VBA_REG_NIS2,VBA_REG_NIS3),,COLUMN()-@COLUMN(VBA_REG_NIS1)+1))`

Than I was dissapointed to find that not all computers in my company have the new formula, so I was thinking maybe I can replicate the functionality in VBA.
I tried using the formula below, but when I applied the `sum(index(vStack_clone` that I mentioned earlier, I noticed that I'm only getting the total from the first named range, as if the Union actually does horizontal stacking.

```
Function vStack_clone(ParamArray ranges() As Variant) As Range
    Dim I As Long
    
    For I = LBound(ranges) To UBound(ranges)
        If I = LBound(ranges) Then
            Set vStack_clone = ranges(I)
        Else
            Set vStack_clone = Union(vStack_clone, ranges(I))
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Can anyone help me clone the VSTACK formula, maybe tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: The following question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71112859/3688861

Answer (score 1):

### VSTACK RANGES UDF

- The result of the following function as well as the result of Excel's `VSTACK` function is not a range but an array.
- Note that functions like `COUNTIF`, `SUMIF`...etc. work only with ranges and you won't be able to use them.

[image]

```vb
Function VStackRanges(ParamArray Ranges() As Variant) As Variant
    
    Dim LB As Long, UB As Long: LB = LBound(Ranges): UB = UBound(Ranges)
    Dim sData(): ReDim sData(LB To UB)
    Dim srCounts(): ReDim srCounts(LB To UB)
    Dim scCounts(): ReDim scCounts(LB To UB)
    
    Dim Data(), n As Long, drCount As Long, dcCount As Long
    
    For n = LB To UB
        srCounts(n) = Ranges(n).Rows.Count
        scCounts(n) = Ranges(n).Columns.Count
        drCount = drCount + srCounts(n)
        If scCounts(n) > dcCount Then dcCount = scCounts(n)
        If srCounts(n) * scCounts(n) = 1 Then
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = Ranges(n).Value
        Else
            Data = Ranges(n).Value
        End If
        sData(n) = Data
    Next n
    
    ReDim Data(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    Dim sr As Long, sc As Long, dr As Long
    
    For n = LB To UB
        For sr = 1 To srCounts(n)
            dr = dr + 1
            For sc = 1 To scCounts(n)
                Data(dr, sc) = sData(n)(sr, sc)
            Next sc
        Next sr
    Next n
    
    VStackRanges = Data

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Union` doesn't work for discontiguous ranges, so it's only picking up the first range argument you enter.

The below code works for me, but I have only tried it in MS365:

```
Function vStack_clone(ParamArray ranges() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim lWidth As Long, lHeight As Long, tmpOutput As Variant
    Dim a As Long, x As Long, y As Long, SeriesY As Long
    
    'Set spill range dimensions
    For a = LBound(ranges) To UBound(ranges)
        If ranges(a).Columns.Count > lWidth Then lWidth = ranges(a).Columns.Count
        lHeight = lHeight + ranges(a).Rows.Count
    Next
    
    ReDim tmpOutput(1 To lHeight, 1 To lWidth)
    SeriesY = 1

    'Enter Values
    For a = LBound(ranges) To UBound(ranges)
        For y = 1 To ranges(a).Rows.Count
            For x = 1 To ranges(a).Columns.Count
                tmpOutput(SeriesY, x) = ranges(a).Cells(y, x)
            Next
            SeriesY = SeriesY + 1
        Next
    Next
    
    vStack_clone = tmpOutput
    
End Function
```